# Which attribute type should I use for price?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes

I want users to select a price range (collection), but they will also have the option "I don't know", so I can't make **Price** an integer because the "I don't know option" will not save to the ddbb... Should I make **Price** a string?

NOTE: Afterwards I will make an advanced search with "Search by price"

#### Update #1

I want the user to select a price from a price range. In that price range Ill have also 2 more options: "I don't know", and "Fixed price". If the user selects I don't know, how can I handle this? If the user selects "Fixed price", how can I tell Simple form I need a new input for this new value?

#### Update #2

My collection:

```
<%= f.input :price, collection: ["0-10","11-20","21-50","51-100","101-200","201-500","500-1000","1000-2000","2000-4000", "Más de 4000"], label: "¿Cuanto te costó?" ,placeholder: "Euros aproximados", html_input: "required", input_html: {class: 'ipt'} %>
```

#### Update #3

I added this:

```
<%= f.input :price, collection: ["-2","-1","0-10","11-20","21-50","51-100","101-200","201-500","500-1000","1000-‌​2000","2000-4000", "Más de 4000"], label: "¿Cuanto te costó?" ,placeholder: "Euros aproximados", html_input: "required", input_html: {class: 'ipt'}, id: "price" %>
```

With price as an id, but it won't work. When I select -2 option, It wont show another input. NOTE: I'm inside a Modal, can It be the reason for it?

#### Update #4

Everything works fine, but I have a problem. Values are stored as -1, -2 only, so when I want to print a products price range , It prints -2. How can I deal to print ranges and "I don't know" values when they are being stored as -1 and -2 in the ddbb? Should I start to think about saving things as strings instead of integers? How do You think I should deal with this?

Another solution? Thanks!

Comment: Ruby on Rails doesn't have some sort of Money type?  And you can't make a field *optional?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since price range cannot be a negative integer, you can have `"I don't know"`'s value to be `-1` and save it, so that:

- It saves memory (Integer is better than String).
- You can have the same data type.
- Money with `-1` value is `"I don't know"`.
- Money with `-2` value is `"Fixed Price"`.

#### Update

Now this is getting complex. Use JavaScript to do this. After putting your collections this way:

```
collection: ["-2","-1","0-10","11-20","21-50","51-100","101-200","201-500","500-1000","1000-2000","2000-4000", "Más de 4000"]
```

Use jQuery to manipulate the input. Say, if it generates the code like this:

```
<select id="price" name="price">
    <option value="-2">-2</option>
    <option value="-1">-1</option>
    <option value="0-10">0-10</option>
    ...
    ...
</select>
```

Now use jQuery and do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#price").find('option[value="-2"]').html("Fixed Price!");
    $("#price").find('option[value="-1"]').html("I don't know!");
    $("#price").change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == -2)
            $('<input type="text" name="customPrice" />').insertAfter(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: The thing is I'm using simple form with a collection as an input... and I don't know how to do this (saving price as a -1)...

Comment: Post your `collection` code in the question, I might be able to help you!

Comment: @Gibson Not sure what that means, but if it's a collection with select box/etc you could have "Unknown" as the label, and "-1" as the value.

Comment: @Gibson Use `-2` for Fixed price.

Comment: @PraveenKumar and how do I tell Simple form: If user selects "Fixed Price", show me another input. How do I handle this?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ok I added this:           <%= f.input :price, collection: ["-2","-1","0-10","11-20","21-50","51-100","101-200","201-500","500-1000","1000-2000","2000-4000", "Más de 4000"], label: "¿Cuanto te costó?" ,placeholder: "Euros aproximados", html_input: "required", input_html: {class: 'ipt'}, id: "price" %> with price as an id, but it won't work. When I select -2 option, It wont show another input. NOTE: I'm inside a Modal, can It be the reason for it?

Comment: @Gibson If you want to add a field after a selection in another you'll need to use JavaScript.

Comment: @DaveNewton I know, but I'm in a modal and I don't know why but JS is not making any effect...:(

Comment: @Gibson That's an entirely separate question; you'll need to ask a new one, including the JS you're running, any JS console output, etc.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Everything works fine, but I have a problem. Values are stored as -1, -2 only, so when I want to print a products price range , It prints -2. How can I deal to print ranges and "I don't know" values when they are being stored as -1 and -2 in the ddbb? Should I start to think about saving things as strings instead of integers? How do You think I should deal with this?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Also , if the user chooses "Fixed Price" as an option, and he introduces his fixed price, only "-2" is being stored and not his fixed price. How can I make the value of fixed price to be stored instead? :(

Comment: @DaveNewton Maybe you could check this out? Thanks!

Comment: Use a simple `if` in the view... :)